# Can we create double tap to turn off screen app?

Tags: android

i have used some smartphone with this cool function, double tap to screen off, then double tap again to turn on. Really dont need to use physical power button (many user want to avoid this) But not every phone have it built in, my question is can we create an app for a phone without this function and without root?
google search resulted all trash

Answer (score 3):

No.  There's no way to get taps when your app isn't the topmost activity, much less when the screen is off.

Comment: cold hard truth :(

Comment: What if it's a system app? Would you know some API or root commands way?

Comment: When the screen is off the touch hardware is generally not powered.  So while you may find some devices that isn't true on, that's generally a no.  When not the topmost activity may be possible with root and reading directly from the /dev/ filesystem to see raw input commands.  But not even a system app would be able to do that, it would need to be root dropping down to the linux layer of the OS